# When i add a UIImageView to a UIScrollView the correct scrolling for iPad does not occur

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have two storyboards, an iPhone and an iPad. Under the iPhone in the storyboard to UIScrollView is already connected UIImageView correctly, when running on the simulator, everything works correctly and xcode does not issue any warnings. And in the storyboard for ipad tried to connect the same UIIMageView to the UIScrollView, but it does not work out correctly and without prejudices.

For different devices, there are two different images with different size, for iPhones a picture with a size of 7+, and for the iPad, the picture size for 12.9. When you start the simulator 7+, the picture by height is displayed completely to the entire height of 7+, and the width is scaled to the right, the width of the picture is large. Accordingly, on smaller iPhones, when displaying a picture, in height it will take up more space than the height of the phone screen and will also scroll up / down + to the right. The same effect I try to achieve and for ipad. I tried to bind everything via reset to suggested, as well as just add the constants for UIImageView relative to UIScrollView, but still it does not work. Although I do everything the same way as I did for an iPhone. Please help. Thank's

My project https://yadi.sk/d/WU7tjwEv3NNRm6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekRgd.jpg)

Comment: What do u mean by "And in the storyboard for ipad tried to connect the same UIIMageView to the UIScrollView" U are trying to add image view as subview to UIScrollView ? Or trying to connect IBOutlet of ImageView to scrollView which is technically not possible anyway

Comment: BTW UIIMageView has intrinsic content size. Which means unless u apply auto layout constraints which directly or indirectly decides the frame of UIImageView, imageView will take up the space based on the content being set. Adding multiple images each for one size of iPhone or iPad will increase the size of ur app bundle and not a proper approach. Rather add image with content mode as ScaleTofill/AspectFill/AspectFit based on ur need and then ship out app with single large image and apply trailing/leading/top and bottom constraints that way ur image view will always take the frame of screen

Comment: and because of content mode set image will either fit or scale to match the frame.

Comment: I took a look at your project files... Very confusing! In design mode for your "iPhone Storyboard", you have selected `View as: iPhone 8 Plus - Portrait Orientation`,  but then you select **Freeform** for the Simulated Metrics and change the dimensions???? What are you actually trying to do? Do you want a scroll view that covers the full screen, and this image should fit to the height and scroll horizontally? Or the image should scroll both ways?

Comment: I'm trying to make sure that on maximally large devices (iphone 8+ and ipad  pro 12.9) there was a kind of scrolling that covers the full screen, and this image should fit to the height and scroll horizontally. And for smaller devices in size, the image should scroll in both ways. But on the storyboard for iPad I can not achieve this result

Comment: I have very little experience in development. Therefore, I do not understand how to do it correctly "Adding multiple images each for one size of iPhone or iPad will ............" I do what I need, but I do not get the right result. Could you edit my project and give it to me? I'll try to understand the solved problem. Thank you very much

Comment: @DonMag - Сможет ли ты мне помочь?

Comment: It is still not completely clear what you really want to do. It's a bit unusual to take the approach you have with different images. Do you want the user to be able to Zoom? Do you need landscape and portrait orientation? Will you be adding additional subviews? I'd suggest you get to know the fundamentals of `UIScrollView` first - search on `uiscrollview pan and zoom` and read through some articles / tutorials to get a better idea of what you *want* to do, and what you *need* to do.